# How do I put a wordpress blog into my html site?

Tags: html, blog, customization

ok, so have a html site with css and I want to put a wordpress blog page in it, but I want it to be in the same site I already have.

I've read the integrating wordpress with your website thing and I think i've done it.

I set up a new page on the site where I have the header and nothing else, but I don't exactly know what to do next in order to make it work.

I'm very lost, hah.

help would be amazing!

Comment: You can keep your existing HTML website but you can install WordPress in domain.com/blog folder. You will be able to manage your blog from WordPress admin except static HTML website.

Comment: Try installing Wordpress in a subfolder like /blog and link it with you HTML navigation. And link your Blog navigation back to HTML site.

Answer (score 2):

Either install wordpress in a subdomain (blog.yoursite.com or sub folder (yoursite.com/blog) 
Design the WordPress site exactly like your current website to get a consistent design.

Or make your entire website in WordPress. WordPress can be used for many other things than blogging.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for an `<iframe src="domain.com/blog"></iframe>` solution, however I would advise against that for many a reason the primary being it is arguably creating a "blackhole" of content from an SEO perspective.

The way it's usually done is install WordPress in a subfolder, traditionally `yourdomain.com/blog` and then link back and forth between your "site" and your "blog"

If you're literally stuck on "How do I install WordPress" there are plenty of guides, including [the official one on WordPress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) or alternatively most hosting providers have the ability to do it in their hosting section. Look for it under "Apps" or "Fantastico"

Comment: ok so i'm using godaddy. so i installed go daddy on my site. I guess what i don't understand is the actual putting in of the blog. i followed this http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website

and i made a new page with the header and everything and those bits of code. I just don't know how I actually go about getting the blog into the page that I made for the blog

Comment: If you want WordPress under your header, you're going to either use the iframe solution or create a custom theme for it to work with underneath

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but it might be helpful for someone.

Every blog on wordpress supports **feeds** so to sync your blog posts on any site you just need to fetch the feeds from the same url of your blog like **www.yourblogname.wordpress.com/feed/**. This will return RSS feeds which can be used anyway you want.

There are lot of jQuery plugins to read feeds like http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

Comment: This was actually the answer that helped me although the link is broken. I used this jquery plugin in the end: https://github.com/enginkizil/FeedEk

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in Mind the SEO requirements, plus that you want to have a Folder and its Subfolders to start having WordPress. Its better to go with WordPress Installation in its own Subdirectory. Check the below WordPress official Link with steps to install it in Subdirectory. You need to look at Step 4 under - Famous 5-Minute Installation.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

Hope this helps!

Manjunath Thandu
http://www.zivoke.com
Salesforce Consultants